# Alternative to numpy.random.poisson() for drawin a SINGLE poisson distributed random number

Tags: python

I noticed that drawing **single** random numbers using `numpy.random` is generally way slower than using `random`, obviously because `numpy.random` is optimized for drawing a bunch of random numbers in one shot. E.g., timings for sampling a random integer from a list are shown here:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
import random
import numpy
'''
min(timeit.Timer('numpy.random.choice(range(100))',setup=setup).repeat(10, int(1e4)))
min(timeit.Timer('random.choice(range(100))', setup=setup).repeat(10, int(1e4)))
```

numpy.random: 0.1427

random : 0.0095

Now I need to draw single poission distributed random variables with **variable** lambda parameter, which implies that I cannot generation a bunch of them in one run for later usage. Hence, I seek an alternative to `numpy.random.poisson()`, because I expect, analogous to the above result, that using it will extremely slow me down. However, `random` does not offer the poisson distribution (why?).

Answer (score 0):

You can create all values at once by passing in an iterable of lambdas:

```
numpy.random.poisson(lam=numpy.arange(200), size=(100, 200))
```

this will return 100 values for each of the 200 different lambda (100 * 200 values in total) values in one execution.

Comment: This is unfortunately not useful for my purpose, I really need a fast method to draw single poisson random variables.

Comment: Then simply do `size=(1, 200)`. That's one random number for each of the 200 individual lambda values.

Comment: Or do you mean your lambda value cannot be determined beforehand?

Comment: Yes, kind of it cannot be determined beforehand.